# Make nodemon ignore changes in all other files except the one it's running in the same folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I am running multiple Discord bots from the same folder. Each is controlled by a single .js file. The problem I have is that whenever I make code changes to one of them, all of the bots restart. I can use the `--ignore` command to make one instance ignore changes to everything in the folder, but it also ignores changes to itself. I've tried these two versions in a command line:

```
nodemon --ignore *.js
nodemon --ignore *.js --watch index.js
```

In both cases, the index.js bot doesn't restart when I make changes to it. Is there a way to make it restart on changes to itself while ignoring all other files? I'd prefer not to have to move all these bots into separate folders, which I think is one way to make it work, as that would be more of a hassle and scramble up my existing local source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to specify multiple `--ignore` parameters. So you can do like the following

```
nodemon --ignore bot1.js --ignore bot2.js bot3.js
nodemon --ignore bot1.js --ignore bot3.js bot2.js
nodemon --ignore bot3.js --ignore bot2.js bot1.js
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that would be another option. It'll just be a bit of a hassle since I have quite a few different bots running. I'm upvoting this for now, and if no other answers pop up I'll accept it in a couple days. Thanks.